# SSRS how to change the parameter position in web part?

Tags: reporting-services, position, ssrs-2008

Currently I Have my parameters shown on the right side of web part as the snapshot shows.

[image]

However, I need to move the parameters filter to the top of webpart. Also, it should be still within the webpart. How could I make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with the existing Web part. If you need parameters in a different spot, you'll need to create a custom Web part.